# why does lsp clangd linting throws an error "bits/c++config.h file not found?

Tags: windows, include-path, language-server-protocol, clangd, nvim-lspconfig

lsp linting clangd throws a linting error
when doing an include
e.g
#include <iostream>  error bits/c++config.h file not found

I already installed mingw(via choco install) and added it to my path
also tried added the includes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoJxR.png)

same with LLVM!
[image]

but when I tried to build a hello world program using cmake it works
as expected.
[image]

I also copied the compile_command.json to my root generated by cmake
[image]

I been spending 2 days to solve this, but still no luck

here's the linting problem. (lsp clangd windows)
[image]

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I inspect the <iostream> and explore the file where bits/c++config.h located but
I it wasn't there, this causing  the linter issue. but I don't get it when I tried to build it, it works just fine.

Comment: after further exploration I found out that removing the LLVM on the path removes the linting error but it also removes the linting part lsp clangd. 
right now I reinstalling the llvm using via https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-14.0.0
I remembered that when I installed llvm using choco install somewhere in the middle of the download, it stops on a certain percent. 
so I stop it and reinstall it using the same method but it said that It was already installed, That's what I think so I continue.  this probably cause the issue, maybe some missing files or sort of.

Comment: Update: after reinstalling llvm, linters are working again and completion, but still 
gives me a linting error of standard library not being found.

Comment: running clang++ -v gives me: 

clang version 14.0.0

Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

Thread model: posix

InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also added -DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS=-I<cpp_include_path>
on cmake flag. clangd reads the compile_command.json generated by cmake and the iostream but it missing something, the<bits/c++config.h>, it is located on the other folder on the same directory where iostream is located named x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits ,
I tried to copy its contents and added it to the /bits folder but it gives me another error
and so on.

Comment: this is what I use to generate the build type
cmake -S . -B build -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=" -IC:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0" "C:\Devs\software\cpp"

Comment: forget to mention that I a use gcc --version 
g++.exe (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 11.2.0
and for llvim I use 14.0.0

Answer (score 0):

the include errors occur because of wrong lsp clangd config

Finally. ah. sigh.. I fixed it. I'm doing things wrong from the start.
there's no need to add flags to include everything e.g -I that has been missing. There's nothing wrong on the clangd itself. The problem lies on your lsp config.

I'm using windows,powershell, no wsl, nvim -> lunarvim and cmake
the fix is simple you just need to add the compile command path
on your --query-driver on your clang lsp config

after that everything should work nice and smooth

Answer (score 0):

the include errors occur because of wrong lsp clangd config

here is my solution for solving the issue

here's the path that you should have into your --query-driver,
remember it depends on your compile_command.json.

[compile_command.json generated by cmake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZJKZ.png)

Your --query-driver should be the same as your command path listed on your compile_command.json

[lsp clangd config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqqBz.png)

after that errors about missing includes should gone by now

[errors gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuOQ7.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).